# Xhtml code is not in working order in CSS, how to properly format to get things working?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I'm just learning CSS and I'm not sure why the ordering of things are affecting how things work on my page. The top element is always showing up while the others aren't working. Sometimes when I order things, two things will work one won't but usually one will work the other 2 won't. I have the header first in the body, out of these elements. Then I have the unordered list, followed by the ordered list. I'm trying to learn why this is and what I can do to fix my problem. The paragraph works fine though.

```css
ul {font-weight: bold;}

h1 {color: #c6c009;}

ol {font-style: italic;}

p {color: blue; font-family: courier; line-height: 130%;}
```

```html
<p><img src="picture.jpg" height="200" /></p>

<h1> header </h1>
<p>paragraph.<br /> other part.</p>
<hr />
<h2> second header</h2>
<ul>
  <li>nyc</li>
  <li>boston</li>
  <li>philly</li>
  <li>baltimore</li>
</ul>

<ol>
  <li>nyc</li>
  <li>boston</li>
  <li>philly</li>
  <li>baltimore</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Could you show us your HTML as well?

Comment: I posted the body of my html code, I'm not sure if it's a css thing or a logical thing I'm missing. Again, I'm a beginner at CSS, still learning. I'm trying to learn about CSS as I try to figure out this mishap.

Comment: I created a snippet out of your code, but it works fine. So there must be something else going on, something you haven't shown.

Answer (score 0):

if your element are inside other, you must define it on your css like this:

```
ul > h1 > ol > p { 
    /*some properties for paragraph in the ol with the h1 in the ul*/ 
}
```

Comment: Hey man I added the body to the code, I don't believe I placed any elements inside of each other. When I order the CSS code, some things will work while others won't

Comment: Your statement "you must define it on your css like this" is not true. Even if the OP would have had nested lists with paragraphs inside, they could still have written their CSS the same way.